# Efficiently implementing find-or-create with Realm

Tags: macos, swift, realm

I'm converting a Core Data app on Mac OS X to use Realm.  One function of the app is to maintain a library of files, and in my Core Data code I go to some length to ensure that the data import is performed efficiently.  The techniques I used used mirror [Apple's advice](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html) (which seems to have disappeared) but essentially the pattern is this:

1. Get a list of the files to import
2. Perform a mass query (IN predicate) to determine which files have already been imported.
3. Import the others

This is more efficient in Core Data than checking individual items because it makes one trip to the database instead of one trip per item.

What techniques should be followed in Realm to ensure data is efficiently imported?

Comment: I think it seems also efficient in Realm. For the purposes of accuracy, could you please give more details of the data?

Comment: I'm representing a music library and each song contains various properties such as title and artist, as well as the location on disk stored as a URL.  I only want one song for a given URL in the library so when the user chooses a folder containing 20,000 files I need an efficient way to filter out the existing URLs before adding to avoid duplicates.  I operate in batches and perform a query using an IN predicate for each batch of URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give the following general recommendations:

- Group create operations to large batched write transactions. (You seem to do that already.)
- Add an index / primary key to your URL property.

You can likely query for every single item and create it if needed, nearly as fast as it would be to select relevant items with a large IN predicate. As Realm's query engine is based on an object DSL, there is no real overhead for "a trip to the database". IN predicates are indeed nothing else than a disjunction of multiple index retrievals. So you really just have the difference of constructing multiple small queries vs. constructing a large query via a large `NSPredicate`.